# Wordpress - How to get Post_ID() and echo in Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So I basically want to do something unique for every loop. In my loop, I have a button that links to each post. But I also have an onClick event on the button that appends another class.

So basically, if I click a button, it adds a class that turns the button red. Also, I had to put the `<script>` tag in the loop because otherwise, all buttons on the page turn red since the page displays around 5 loops (posts).

So I'm trying to target just one loop's button. (I hope that makes sense).

So here's an example:

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
...

<a class="post-<?php the_ID()?> downloadButton" onClick="downloadSuccess();">text</a>


<script>
  function downloadSuccess() {  
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("downloadButton");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].classList.add("downloadButton-active"); 
}  
} 
</script>


...
?>
```

[image]

What I want is to target each loop's button using the the_ID() **and** the static class.

Example:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.downloadButton,.post-<?php echo the_ID() ?>');
```

But that doesn't work, I guess because you can't echo php inside javascript?

Also, is there a way to not put the javascript inside the loop, yet still target each loop's button based on the_iD()? I would hate to have to put the javascript for every loop just to target the button for each loop.

Can anyone help?

Comment: On your click event handler you could check for a specific class, but for that you'll have to share your `onclick` handler so we can provide further suggestions.

Comment: I have edited the post above. Hopefully it's a little more clear.

Comment: var x = document.querySelectorAll('.downloadButton,.post-'<?php echo the_ID() ?>);

Comment: PHP inside javascript is possible

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="#" id="<?php the_ID()?>" class="downloadButton">text</a>
```

move out from loop:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!event.target.matches('.downloadButton')) return;
    document.getElementById( event.target.id ).classList.add( "active" );
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. In theory it should work, but unfortunately it doesn't. The reason I would like the tag `<?php the_ID()?>` in the class element, instead of ID, is because there are instances where I will have 2 buttons in the loop with the same 'active' class applied. So if someone clicks one of the buttons, both buttons should have the "active" class" amended.